Java-I changed a textField to a ListView and I am not sure how to get it to calculate again
This is homework. Javafx. I needed to replace the Years textField with a comboBox. I have done that, but now when I click calculate, nothing happens. The stack trace shows the error happening at this line
 errorMsg += v.isInteger(yearsField.getText(), 
                "Years");

I think the issue is this needs to be changed so it uses the comboBox selection instead.  I am lost on how to change it. I tried yearCombo.getValue(), but that did not work. Im hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. Appreciate any help.
package com.murach.future_value;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FutureValueApplication extends Application {
    private TextField investmentField;
    private TextField interestRateField;
    private TextField yearsField;
    private TextField futureValueField;
    private ComboBox<Integer> yearCombo = new ComboBox<>();
    private ListView<String> futureValueView = new ListView<>();
    {
    
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Future Value Calculator");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);

        grid.add(new Label("Monthly Investment:"), 0, 0);
        investmentField = new TextField();
        grid.add(investmentField, 1, 0);

        grid.add(new Label("Yearly Interest Rate:"), 0, 1);
        interestRateField = new TextField();
        grid.add(interestRateField, 1, 1);

        grid.add(new Label("Years:"), 0, 2);
        ComboBox<Integer> yearCombo = new ComboBox<>();
        grid.add(yearCombo, 1,2);
        yearCombo.setPromptText("Select Years");
        Integer[] years = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        for(int year: years){
            yearCombo.getItems().add(year);
        }
        
        Integer year = yearCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        grid.add(new Label("Future Value:"), 0, 3);
        futureValueView = new ListView<>();
        futureValueField = new TextField();
        futureValueView.setPrefHeight(5*24);
        futureValueField.setEditable(false);
        grid.add(futureValueField, 1, 3);

        Button calculateButton = new Button("Calculate");
        calculateButton.setOnAction(event -> calculateButtonClicked());

        Button exitButton = new Button("Exit");
        exitButton.setOnAction(event -> exitButtonClicked());

        HBox buttonBox = new HBox(10);
        buttonBox.getChildren().add(calculateButton);
        buttonBox.getChildren().add(exitButton);
        buttonBox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        grid.add(buttonBox, 0, 4, 2, 1);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void calculateButtonClicked() {
        Validation v = new Validation();          
        String errorMsg = "";
        errorMsg += v.isDouble(investmentField.getText(), 
                "Monthly Investment");
        errorMsg += v.isDouble(interestRateField.getText(), 
                "Yearly Interest Rate");
        errorMsg += v.isInteger(yearsField.getText(), 
                "Years");

        if (errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
            double investment = Double.parseDouble(
                    investmentField.getText());
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(
                    interestRateField.getText());
            int years = Integer.parseInt(
                    yearsField.getText());
            
            
           
        ListView<String> futureValueList = calculateFutureValue(investment, rate, years);
           futureValueView.getItems().setAll(futureValueList.getItems());
            ListView<String> futureValue = calculateFutureValue(
                    investment, rate, years);

            NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
            futureValueField.setText(currency.format(futureValue));
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setHeaderText("Invalid Data");
            alert.setContentText(errorMsg);
            alert.showAndWait();        
        }
    }

    public ListView<String> calculateFutureValue(double investment, double rate, int years) {
        double futureValue = 0.0;
        ListView<String> listview = new ListView<>();
        // convert yearly values to monthly values
        double monthlyInterestRate = rate / 12 / 100;
        int months = years * 12;

        for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++) {
            futureValue = (futureValue + investment)
                    * (1 + monthlyInterestRate);
            int currentYear = (i-1/12+1);
            if(i % 12 == 0){
                listview.getItems().add("Year " + currentYear + ": $"+ futureValue);
            }
        }
        return listview;
    }

    private void exitButtonClicked() {
        System.exit(0);   // 0 indicates a normal exit
    }
}

I think I need to use yearCombo instead of yearsField in the calculateButtonClicked method, but when I try to replace it, I get an error.

Consider these changes:
1. Add an object property to the grid instead of a local variable. Change
ComboBox<Integer> yearCombo = new ComboBox<>();
grid.add(yearCombo, 1, 2);

to
yearCombo = new ComboBox<>();
grid.add(yearCombo, 1, 2);

2. Use yearCombo.getValue():
errorMsg += v.isInteger(String.valueOf(yearCombo.getValue()), 
        "Years");

if (errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
    double investment = Double.parseDouble(
            investmentField.getText());
    double rate = Double.parseDouble(
            interestRateField.getText());

    int years = yearCombo.getValue();

3. Output the last of futureValueView in futureValueField. Replace
futureValueField.setText(currency.format(futureValue));

with
futureValueField.setText(futureValue.getItems().get(futureValue.getItems().size() - 1));

